# MVCArray get last element

Tags: jquery, arrays, gwt

How can I check what is the last inserted,or pushed, element to a `MVCArray` so I can use it in an `if` statement, using *jQuery*?

```
if(MVCArray.getLast == 'something') {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Is it an associative array? Or an array with only values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before asking something, make sure you [read the documentation](https://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/3.8/com/google/maps/gwt/client/MVCArray.html).

You have the `pop()` method that returns the last element of the array, but also removes it (per the documentation).

I suppose you don't want to remove it, so you can use `getAt(double i)`, which returns an element from a certain index. The last inserted element will be at the last index (i.e. `length - 1`), so you have to do:

```
yourArray.getAt(yourArray.getLength() - 1)
```

in order to get the last element.

```
if(yourArray.getAt(yourArray.getLength() - 1) == 'something') {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your advice, and explaining the solution, which worked perfectly.